# what is Docker Channel?

Tags: docker

I am using Docker on WSL and I found the term "Docker channel" with releases Edge and Stable. What does "Docker channel" refer to? Is it an interface to connect docker on Windows to that on WSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate parallel release trains of Docker, which Docker calls "channels".  "Stable" is pretty well tested; "edge" is kind of like a late beta.  [About Docker CE](https://docs.docker.com/install/) also discusses three release channels for the core (Community Edition) engine, and the [Docker for Windows FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/) discusses this in some detail.

If you're not sure then you should pick usually the "stable" channel.

The "edge channel" has some features that are slightly more experimental.  In the Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac desktop applications, "edge" in particular includes a built-in optional local Kubernetes deployment, in the same space as `minikube` but lighter-weight.  "Edge" also has more frequent releases.

Answer (score 0):

The ***Edge*** Channel is [deprecated and no longer receives updates](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/14004).

If you go to the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Docker repo-  https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/ - you'll see  ***Edge*** there, but if you look into the folder it hasn't been updated since Sept 2020.

So it's still possible to subscribe to the ***Edge*** Docker Channel, but it will never be updated.

The Docker documentation still references "***Edge***" in places, but not specifically in the "Channels" section causing on-going confusion. Therefore ignore any references to the ***Edge*** Channel when reviewing Docker documentation; it's as dead as a Norwegian Blue parrot...